# Equals Method with two integers

Tags: java, equals

I want to override the equals method. But in my class are two integers. I want to ask you if the equalsMethode  is correct.

like this?

thank you

edit 1:
my problem is, i want to remove an object of typ field of a

Comment: Just an advice: Use else if instead of multiple if statements. Also you can use "or" to compare statements that returns same values.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is subject to opinion. In my opinion your implementation is not right. Starter why convert int to String?

Comment: at the last line int value don't have to be converted into String to check if they are equal, you can just use == operator to compare.

Comment: Why are you converting row and column to Strings before comparing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than a couple of syntax errors, the implementation is not incorrect. However, the conversions to string are unnecessary:

```
return other.getRow() == getRow() && other.getColumn() == getColumn();
```

Other points:

1. The `if (this == obj)` check is redundant.
2. The `if (getClass() != obj.getClass())` check may or may not be desirable, depending on whether you intend to ever subclass `Field` (I note that it is not declared `final`).

Last but not least, having overridden `equals()`, you should also override `hashCode()`. See [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) for a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This is your equals method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Field other = (Field) obj;
    if (column != other.column)
        return false;
    if (row != other.row)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

and this is your hashCode mthod:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + column;
        result = prime * result + row;
        return result;
    }
```